# How to copy cell if condition (yellow colorhighlight) is met and paste in another cell?

Tags: excel

I have a big table with different dates. I used conditionnal formatting to highlight all the days in yellow that are 45 days in the future from present day. This worked.

Now i want another table, on the same sheet, to tell me which compagnies are highlighted.

We can see all the compagnies on A1.

Comment: Use the Filter to Filter Out Highlighted Rows and Paste Them on a new Sheet.

Comment: Better use `Advance Filter` to copy data to another location based on conditions.